# CSS overflow value for chat

Tags: css, overflow

I build a chat application and i have an issue with the overflow property i think..
I want when a user connects to chat to show him the last message without him have to scroll down to the last message.When a user connects to chat by default it shows the first message and user have to scroll down.
my css is:

```
.chat{
  height: 175px;
  width: 488px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even i extand the height if there is 120 lines of chatting again the user have to scroll until he reach the last line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this purely with css, you'll need to use javascript.

```
var chatDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('chat')[0]; //I assume you only have one chat box!
chatDiv.scrollTop = chatDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 6):

Per default `overflow` happens to right or bottom. You have to use some other technique for this.

One would be: Use a wrapper and position your chat messages absolutely to bottom:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="chat"></div>
</div>
```

With css:

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 175px;
    width: 488px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chat{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Linus i understand,do you have something in your mind to try?